# Acronis True Image 9 booted from USB doesn't work

Tags: usb, backup, acronis-trueimage

When I try to make a HDD backup using Acronis True Image 9 booted from a USB flash drive, it says something like:

> Cannot perform the operation because this is the unregistered trial version.

This, however, is not true. I am using the registered version. Is there a license file that I need to copy to the USB flash drive?

How I set up the drive:

http://kb.acronis.com/sites/default/files/content/2006/3/1526/flash-syslinux.html

Answer (score 0):

Try making the bootable USB drive as described in the manual, see chapter 9

http://download.acronis.com/pdf/TrueImage9.0_ug.en.pdf

Comment: That's what I tried first. However, the flash drive did not boot at all. Yes, it was freshly Fat32 formatted, with one primary partition.

Answer (score 0):

First, do you have "Acronis True Image Home **full** version" which supports USB?

Second, I had problems with booting version 9 even from CD, which went away when I upgraded to version 2010.

You might consider upgrading to the latest version 2011, on which you are more likely to receive effective support from Acronis.

Comment: Yes, I do have the *full* (paid) version. What prevented me from upgrading are reports about serious bugs in versions 2010 and 2011. True Image 2009 works reliably on my system. The broken USB support, though, gives me another reason to avoid products by that company.

Comment: Version 2010 works very reliably, and has already saved my backside several times. So well indeed that I will probably only upgrade to version 2011 when I move to Windows 7. However, I use a boot CD and cannot testify for USB, but the latest version must have fixed this kind of deficiencies. I have several times compared Acronis to other products, but was never motivated to change.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Harry! However, I still hope to find a way to make version 2009 boot from USB.

Comment: Then I suggest either requesting support from Acronis or its forums.